# Flash create mini window for HTML

Tags: html, flash

Is there a way to create a mini window in flash that contain an HTML web page?

Not open in new window!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not. It is possible in AIR, but not in the web player.

You can sort of hack it by putting an iframe above or below (provided the flash is transparent) the flash object. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750605/html-flex-display-flash-behind-html/2751494#2751494) is similar. But this "solution" is usually not very good.